# How to subclass range in Python?

Tags: python, range

How to subclass the `range` type in Python? (I want to represent an indexable sequence of very large objects)

The minimal example below raises `TypeError: type 'range' is not an acceptable base type`.

```py
class OffsetRange(range):

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return i+1

OffsetRange()
```

Comment: It's a built-in type that can't be subclassed. You can proxy it, if you need to, but it might be fiddly to get right for all the special methods supported by `range`s.

Comment: Why so complicated? `range` doesn't have to start at zero, and can easily handle large numbers?

Comment: @YSelf Because I want to return a dataset, not just `i+1`. The example is just for reference.

Comment: @CarlosPinzón I'm not sure what a dataset would be in this case. The answer to your literal question is what AKX said, you can't subclass range. You can of course write a class with `__iter__`, `__getitem__`, etc, returning what you want.